Laravel filament - how to properly inject services into filament stuff?
for example how would you inject into a
use Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords;

class ListBankTransactions extends ListRecords{...}

we could use app(MyService:class) but that feels just ugly to me. Any other ways?
other places I should know about and how to properly inject? I checked their docs. I checked example projects (didnt open all files though) but couldnt find anything.
I tried injecting via
public function mount(MyService $myservice) but that didnt work

If I understood you correctly then you can use a constructor:
use Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords;

class ListBankTransactions extends ListRecords
{
    protected MyService $myService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->myService = app(MyService::class);
    }
}

